# How can I select only the values in a dataframe without Rstudio showing me also the row name?

Tags: r

I made some code in Rstudio in my Windows PC, and I'm now working on another PC with Ubuntu. I'm running the code in the second PC, and when trying to call some attribute on a data.frame, the console also gives me the row name.

```
> estaciones_region_atrb[,1]
       X3        X4        X5        X6        X7        X8        X9       X10       X11       X12 
X05704002 X05740004 X05704004 X05716004 X05702011 X05702001 X05716001 X05701008 X05716011 X05716005 
      X13       X14       X15       X16       X17       X18       X19       X20       X21       X22 
X05747001 X05701005 X06040001 X06011003 X06042004 X06042003 X06010014 X06011001 X06010015 X06044001 
      X23       X24       X25       X26       X27       X28       X29       X30       X31       X32 
X06008009 X06006001 X06010016 X06019003 X06019005 X06012003 X06003001 X06000003 X06000004 X06015003 
      X33       X34       X35       X36       X37       X38       X39       X40       X41       X42 
X06013005 X06018009 X06013001 X06013006 X06018010 X06013008 X06016004 X06034004 X06027001 X06028001 
      X43       X44       X45       X46 
X06027003 X06034003 X06036001 X07106007 
45 Levels: codigo_estacion X05701005 X05701008 X05702001 X05702011 X05704002 X05704004 ... X07106007
```

As you can see, "X3", "X4" etc are the row names. This is interfering with the rest of the work, since now R interprets the string as a longer one. In the case of numerics, it transforms into a string.

This doesn't happen on my Windows PC. What's going on?

Comment: `unname(..)` removes names

Comment: Thank you! It works :)